# Rad Html chart grouping

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, radhtmlchart

My question is about how to group XAsis in Telerik rad Html chart?
The image below shows the current state of my the Html Column chart:
[image]
All I want to know is how to group the XAsis by month so it won't repeat. Something like in this:

[image]

```html
<telerik:radhtmlchart runat="server" id="RadHtmlChart1" OnLoad="RadHtmlChart1_Load" Width="800px" Height="500px"  >
    <PlotArea>
        <Series>
            <telerik:ColumnSeries  DataFieldY="TotalAdded" Stacked="true" >
              
                <Appearance>
                   
                            <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#d5a2bb"  ></FillStyle>
                        </Appearance>
              

                <LabelsAppearance Position="InsideEnd">

                    <ClientTemplate >
                       
                        #=dataItem.EventCode# 
                    </ClientTemplate>
                   
                </LabelsAppearance>
                
                        
            </telerik:ColumnSeries>


            


        </Series>


        <XAxis Color="Black" MajorTickType="Outside" MinorTickType="Outside" Reversed="false" Name="xAug" DataLabelsField="MonthName">
   
             <MinorGridLines Visible="false"></MinorGridLines>
                    <MajorGridLines Visible="false"></MajorGridLines>
             <LabelsAppearance RotationAngle="75"   >

                    
             </LabelsAppearance>
                 
           
            <MajorGridLines Color="#EFEFEF" Width="1" />
            <MinorGridLines Color="#F7F7F7" Width="1" />
            <TitleAppearance Position="Center" RotationAngle="0" Text="Months" />

    
       
                 <LabelsAppearance RotationAngle="75" Skip="0" Step="1"></LabelsAppearance>
                    <TitleAppearance Position="Center" RotationAngle="0" Text="Quarters">
                    </TitleAppearance>



                </XAxis>

    </PlotArea>

             <Legend>
                <Appearance Visible="false">
                </Appearance>
            </Legend>
</telerik:radhtmlchart>
```